# How to convert SPARQL statements to graph pattern queries?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases

I am seeking for an online tool or a parser (e.g. in the form of a program) that is able to convert SPARQL statements to visible graph pattern queries.

In other words, I am seeking a way to convert SPARQL query templates to query graphs. An online tool, an offline source code, or an algorithm (pseudocode) works for me.
You may find an example in [this page](https://dsg.uwaterloo.ca/watdiv/basic-testing.shtml) of WatDiv benchmark.

For instance, how can I convert the following SPARQL statement to a connected set of nodes and edges as a graph query (i.e. a list of human-readable (labeled)-nodes and edges)?

```
SELECT * 
WHERE 
  { ?v0   <http://schema.org/eligibleRegion>                 <http://db.uwaterloo.ca/~galuc/wsdbm/Country5> .  
    ?v0   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/includes>           ?v1 .
    ?v2   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/offers>             ?v0 .  
    ?v0   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/price>              ?v3 .  
    ?v0   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/serialNumber>       ?v4 .  
    ?v0   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/validFrom>          ?v5 .  
    ?v0   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/validThrough>       ?v6 .  
    ?v0   <http://schema.org/eligibleQuantity>               ?v8 .  
    ?v0   <http://schema.org/priceValidUntil>                ?v11 .  
    ?v1   <http://ogp.me/ns#tag>                             ?v7 .  
    ?v1   <http://schema.org/keywords>                       ?v10 .  
    ?v12  <http://db.uwaterloo.ca/~galuc/wsdbm/purchaseFor>  ?v1 .  
  }
```

Comment: Query question doesn't reflect what you want. You just want to visualize the SPARQL query resp. it's triple patterns as a graph. This is trivial, isn't it? Given that each triple pattern denotes a labeled directed edge, you have all you need. I did it in JGraphT some years ago. Took me probably 20 lines of code to create the graph and then export it to GraphML format. What's the difficulty here?

Comment: Your actual need/goal/desire is unclear to me. You *may* be looking for something like [iSPARQL](https://github.com/OpenLinkSoftware/iSPARQL), which you can find live and usable on the Virtuoso instances hosting [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/) or [URIBurner](http://uriburner.com/isparql/), among many others.

Comment: Thanks, @AKSW. Since I'm a newbie to SPARQL query language. Thus, for example, I don't know what "<http://purl.org/goodrelations/includes> ?v1.?v2" exactly means. v1->v2 where v1 label is "includes"? or the relationship type is "include". Of course, I can figure it out by myself. However, it's good to have a ready answer here for others too!

Comment: Thanks, @TallTed. I need to convert SPARQL queries like what I've put here to a set of labeled nodes/edges. e.g. Person->Location, Location->Order, etc to extract a graph out of it.

Comment: So you're wanting to translate queries from the SPARQL Query Language into some (other) Graph Query Language? Or, *maybe*, you're trying to turn a SPARQL Query into something like an niche-/task-ontology or a SHACL-ish shape?  Since you say you don't quite understand SPARQL, I've edited the whitespace of your SPARQL query to hopefully make what it's doing a bit clearer. Each line there is a triple -- i.e., a Subject → Predicate → Object -- which together provides a (hopefully) clear graph shape, which should be trivially convertible to an illustration.

Comment: @TallTed he just wants to visualize the SPARQL query as a graph.

Comment: @mhn_namak No, you didn't understand it. The SPARQL query is made of triple pattern. Each triple pattern simply denotes a single edge between two nodes. For example, `?v0   <http://purl.org/goodrelations/includes>           ?v1 .` means you have a node labeled `?v0` and another node labeled `?v1` and between those nodes you have an edge labeled `http://purl.org/goodrelations/includes` - that's all.

Comment: You will have to clarify the last bit: "as a graph query". please. I cannot parse it. Tx